# facebook share button statistics

Tags: facebook, statistics, share

I have a dynamic website, and use the share button on various pages of my site. All share her homepage.

An example:

- mydomain.com/?c=product&id=1
- mydomain.com/?c=article&id=1
- mydomain.com/

all these pages have the facebook share button, and all share this page mydomain.com/

know any way to know when shares were made? how many shares have? Which of my pages was made a share? and eventually who have shared?

it is possible to get this kind of statistics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a lot of information from where people got your links from, by analyzing your server logs.  There's lots of tools to do this.  Contact your server admin or webmaster to find out how to get your server logs.

Comment: i know that, but i'm searching only for statistics of facebbok share button.

Comment: The sharer.php button is deprecated.  You should be using the like button, which gives you statistics.